# Rotating PDF 90 degrees using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to use a PDF for stamping and need to rotate it 90 degrees to lay it on correctly? Anyone know how to do this? Can't seem to find it online.

Comment: You bind a `PdfStamper` to `PdfReader` but before you do that you are free to manipulate the PDF using any methods available from the `PdfReader` object. See the [official sample here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=232) in Java or a very similar but not exactly same [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5349641/231316) in C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Rotate90Degrees](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/Rotate90Degrees) example uses `PdfReader` to get an instance of the document then changes the `/Rotate` value in every page dictionary. If there is no such entry, a `/Rotate` entry with value `90` is added:

```java
final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
final int pagesCount = reader.getNumberOfPages();

for (int n = 1; n <= pagesCount; n++) {
    final PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(n);
    final PdfNumber rotate = page.getAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
    final int rotation =
            rotate == null ? 90 : (rotate.intValue() + 90) % 360;

    page.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rotation));
}
```

Once this is done, we use a `PdfStamper` to persist the change:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

This is for iText Java. For iTextSharp, porting Java to C# is easy as the terminology is identical. Change some lower cases into upper cases like this:

```
PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(1);
page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
```

There's a more or less identical code snippet in the question part of this post: [How to rotate PDF page with iTextSharp without causing error in ghostscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128286/how-to-rotate-pdf-page-with-itextsharp-without-causing-error-in-ghostscript)

Comment: So I've used this code snippet in C# to rotate each page in a document and then I've used page.GetBytes() to get the bytes for the stream, but how do I go about recombining the pages into a single stream of bytes representing the file?

Answer (score 1):

For C# coders:

I replaced Bruno's answer with C# code:

and yes it's working like a charm, also you can change the rotation number to 180,270, etc

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Source.pdf");
            int pagesCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
            PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(1);
            PdfNumber rotate = page.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
            page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("created.pdf", FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
```