# Rotate printout of pdf in Process.start

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I currently have some code which prints out pdf-files from a disk via process start:

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = documentPath
    }
};
proc.Start();
```

Which is working fine.

I am now looking for a way to help the user sorting the printed out files. These files comes in batches of 1 - x files. My first idea is to rotate every other batch by 180° so the user has a visual clue for which files belong together.

Is there a way to rotate the printout by 180° with the Process-object? If not, is there another simple solution for my problem?
The pdf-file should not be altert, I just want to rotate the printout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating PDF 90 degrees using iTextSharp in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020542/rotating-pdf-90-degrees-using-itextsharp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Only a duplicate if you can rotate the page before printing

Comment: I don't want to rotate the file, just the printout of the file. The file should stay as it is.

Comment: I haven't used that code, or the libraries it uses, but it might be able to rotate the file/page in memory, could be worth looking into it